# composer install requirements could not be resolved but satisfiable requirements are being met

Tags: composer-php

I have this set of requirements for composer:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*@dev",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "3.3.*@dev",
    "zizaco/confide": "~3.2",
    "zizaco/entrust": "~1.2",
    "bllim/datatables": "dev-master",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "4.2.*@dev",
    "fabpot/goutte": "2.*@dev",
    "laravelbook/ardent": "dev-master",
    "anahkiasen/former": "dev-master",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.7.*@dev",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "dev-master",
    "dingo/api": "0.7.*@dev",
    "doctrine/dbal": "2.6.*@dev",
    "mailgun/mailgun-php": "dev-master",
    "iron-io/iron_mq": "dev-master",
    "bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel": "1.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "way/generators": "~2.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects": "2.3.*@dev",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.3.*@dev",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*@dev",
    "summerstreet/woodling": "dev-master",
    "itsgoingd/clockwork": "dev-master",
    "hannesvdvreken/guzzle-clockwork": "dev-master",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "1.5.*@dev",
    "soapbox/laravel-formatter": "dev-master",
    "raveren/kint": "dev-master",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "dev-master"
}
```

When I run `composer install` I get this error message:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravelbook/ardent dev-master -> satisfiable by laravelbook/ardent[dev-master].
    - laravelbook/ardent dev-master requires illuminate/support ~4.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.13, v4.2.14, v4.2.15, v4.2.16, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9], illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.11].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.12].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.13].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.14].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.15].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.16].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.17].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.18].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.19].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.2].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.20].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.21].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.22].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.23].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.24].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.25].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.26].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.27].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.29].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.3].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.30].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.4].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.6].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.7].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.8].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.1.9].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.2.12].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.2.16].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.2.2].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.2.3].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.2.5].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.2.6].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.2.8].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.2.9].
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.1
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.10
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.11
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.12
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.13
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.14
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.15
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.16
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.3
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.4
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.5
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.6
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.7
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.8
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.9
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper dev-master requires illuminate/support 5.0.x -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0].
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper dev-master requires illuminate/filesystem 5.0.x -> satisfiable by illuminate/filesystem[v5.0.0].
    - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper dev-master -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[dev-master].
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this. I need Ardent and I need Laravel 4.2. I've never had a problem installing Ardent with Laravel 4.2 in the past, so I can't figure out why it would be tripped up now, especially since composer says it is satisfiable with the very Laravel version I'm trying to install.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this had nothing to do with Ardent despite the error message. The culprit causing the mayhem was `barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`. When I changed that requirement from `dev-master` to `~1.11` it became compatible with Laravel 4.2 again and all of the other errors went away.

If anyone is having a similar problem, just go through the list and see if any packages were updated to be compatible with 5.0, but not backward compatible with 4.*.